# Odoo - Apps in-memory footprint for multiple databases

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-13

When installing the same Odoo app for multiple databases (tenants), say Sales App, does this mean Odoo will load the same App multiple times in memory, or the App will be loaded once in memory and shared across tenants/DBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo loads the app in a worker (assuming you are using workers) so the app is loaded once per worker. A worker can handle multiple databases if configured. But if you have multiple workers the app might get loaded in each worker as requests are reaching the different workers.

Some part of the memory consumtion of odoo is the ORM caches and those are per database per worker (and some per user) so that part of the App will be in memory multiple times per worker as you have multiple databases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you suggest some reading somewhere in the documentation about this and how it happens?

Comment: As far as I understand, workers are used for concurrency, so we can use multiple workers for a single database to serve a higher number of concurrent users. Does that mean we will still have multiple versions of the same App in memory?

Comment: Well as far as i know there is no single comprehensive link answering you question. Workers are for concurrency, yes (see here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/setup/deploy.html).

I would not run multiple versions (in the sence of code) of the same app on different databases sharing the same odoo instance. As workers are recycled they would load the new code from the filesystem and then your db and code will no longer match.

If version means different data for different databases then yes you can and will have different data for the same App (code) in memory (per user per db).

Comment: Sounds good! So, to sum up, what I understood from you is as follows: Each worker has a complete App object in memory, so, if we have 3 workers, then we will have the same App loaded in memory 3 times. In addition to that, we will have request caching per user per worker per DB. Do I get it right?

Comment: Thanks mate!! Accepted your answer!